# Character encoding problem from Facebook JSON to HTML via PHP

Tags: php, facebook, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm getting a JSON encoded array from Facebook which contains:

> [{"message":"D\u011bkujeme Zuzana
>   Boh\u00e1\u010dov\u00e1 za na\u0161i
>   novou profilovou fotku :-)\nWe thank
>   Zuzana Boh\u00e1\u010dov\u00e1 for our
>   new profile picture :-)"}]

When I decode the JSON and output the contents I get:

> DÄ›kujeme Zuzana BohÃ¡ÄovÃ¡ za naÅ¡i
>   novou profilovou fotku :-) We thank
>   Zuzana BohÃ¡ÄovÃ¡ for our new profile
>   picture :-)

I used `mb_detect_encoding($message)` and it's in utf-8 format but how do I convert the characters ready for human consumption?

Comment: How do you "decode the JSON" and where do you "output the contents"? It works fine in for example this JSON Visualizer: http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting all the correct bytes, but are displaying them incorrectly.

Make sure you are using the correct charset in your content-type header.  The easiest way to do this in PHP is like so

```
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
```

But you are also welcome to do this

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see what I was doing wrong now as the browser didn't know the format to display the characters. Another lesson learnt. I'll mark yours as the answer as you were a whole 15 seconds faster then Daniel ;)

Answer (score 3):

PHP decodes that just fine. When outputting it to the browser, make sure you do something like this so you don't mix character sets in your application:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your answer and Peters did the job perfectly. +1